# How to access Kubernetes runnning in Docker for Windows from another PC

Tags: networking, windows-10, docker-for-windows

I have a desktop PC, ALPHA, where I have installed Docker for Windows with included Kubernetes.

I have a notebook, BETA, where I have installed kubectl. Both are connected to the same WiFi network. I have copied ~.kube\config from ALPHA to BETA and replaced localhost with ALPHA, so the server line says: `server: https://ALPHA:6445`

However, when I run `kubectl version` on BETA, I get an error:

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [ALPHA's_IPv6_address%Wi-Fi]:6445: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I can reach a sample app running on ALPHA:5000 from BETA.

`netstat -an` shows that vpnkit.exe from Docker for Windows is listening on all network interfaces, not just localhost:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:6445           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
```